# How to access a String key in a javascript array of objects?

Tags: javascript, json, object, key

For example, the array is:

```
chipsArray = [{'cheetos':'good'},{'dorritos':'better'}]
```

Here, `chipsArray[0]` would give me `{'cheetos':'good'}`. Let's say I populated this array like the following:

```
chipsArray.push({[chips]:quality})
```

But now that I'm trying to access the `cheetos` or `dorritos` keys in each of objects in this array, I can't. Doing `chipsArray[0].chips` gives me undefined.

As far as I know when populating the key of an object with a certain value/variable, they should be wrapped in square braces. But how can we extract values from them later on when each of these objects are array indices like the example given above? I tried using `Object.keys(chipsArray[index])`, but this only gives me the keys whereas I'm trying to extract the specific value for that specific key.

Tl;Dr: How to extract the key of an object inside an array when the keys are strings like this:

```
chipsArray = [{'cheetos':'good'},{'dorritos':'better'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and get only the first element.

```js
var chipsArray = [{ cheetos: 'good' }, { dorritos: 'better' }];

chipsArray.forEach(function (object) {
    var key = Object.keys(object)[0];
    console.log(key, object[key]);
});
```

Or create an object with the reference to the single objects

```js
var chipsArray = [{ cheetos: 'good' }, { dorritos: 'better' }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

chipsArray.forEach(function (object) {
    hash[Object.keys(object)[0]] = object;
});

console.log(hash['dorritos']['dorritos']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I mentioned in my question that I tried this way. I don't want the key/keys only. I want the value for a certain key that I need to access. For example: I want to pass the key ```'dorritos'``` to get the value ```'better'```. I am unable to access it if I do an ```Object.keys```

Comment: @BobSilas i think this answer silently implies that when you have the key back, it is fairly easy to get the value (just access to the array with your retreived key)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function. It returns the `value` by `key` in the `array`

```
function getItemByKey (key, array) {
    var value;
    array.some(function (obj) {
        if (obj[key]) {
            value = obj[key];
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    return value;
}
```

More about `Array.prototype.some` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to access the value:

```
Object.values(chipsArray[i])
```

where i is the index of the array.

Output:

```
> chipsArray = [{'cheetos':'good'},{'dorritos':'better'}]
[ { cheetos: 'good' }, { dorritos: 'better' } ]
> Object.values(chipsArray[0])
[ 'good' ]
```

Comment: this doesn't work for some reason. Object.keys works just fine but Object.values throws error.

Comment: It should. I have included the output also.